# ggplot assigns wrong colors to hexadecimal colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm assigning hexadecimal colors which are in a df column to ggplot.
However in the plot it shows the names of the hexadecimal colors but not the right colors, colors don't match the hexadecimal colors.

Dataframe and plot code:

```
str(Trun)
'data.frame':   1043 obs. of  12 variables:
$ X       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ DE      : num  36.5 37 40.2 36.8 38.8 ...
$ hex     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...

unique(Trun$hex)
[1] NA        "#8A8F8C" "#507085" "#3F7767" "#917652" "#DBAD5D"

ggplot(data=Trun, aes(x=X, y=DE, colour=hex)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("DE with 35* sd values")
```

Below the data reworked with dput

```
structure(list(X = 1:50, Sample = structure(c(1L, 12L, 23L, 34L, 
45L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L), .Label = c("Sample 1", "Sample 10", 
"Sample 11", "Sample 12", "Sample 13", "Sample 14", "Sample 15", 
"Sample 16", "Sample 17", "Sample 18", "Sample 19", "Sample 2", 
"Sample 20", "Sample 21", "Sample 22", "Sample 23", "Sample 24", 
"Sample 25", "Sample 26", "Sample 27", "Sample 28", "Sample 29", 
"Sample 3", "Sample 30", "Sample 31", "Sample 32", "Sample 33", 
"Sample 34", "Sample 35", "Sample 36", "Sample 37", "Sample 38", 
"Sample 39", "Sample 4", "Sample 40", "Sample 41", "Sample 42", 
"Sample 43", "Sample 44", "Sample 45", "Sample 46", "Sample 47", 
"Sample 48", "Sample 49", "Sample 5", "Sample 50", "Sample 6", 
"Sample 7", "Sample 8", "Sample 9"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(1:50, .Label = c("10:51:04 AM", 
"10:51:05 AM", "10:51:06 AM", "10:51:07 AM", "10:51:08 AM", "10:51:09 AM", 
"10:51:10 AM", "10:51:11 AM", "10:51:12 AM", "10:51:13 AM", "10:51:14 AM", 
"10:51:15 AM", "10:51:16 AM", "10:51:17 AM", "10:51:18 AM", "10:51:19 AM", 
"10:51:20 AM", "10:51:21 AM", "10:51:22 AM", "10:51:23 AM", "10:51:24 AM", 
"10:51:25 AM", "10:51:26 AM", "10:51:27 AM", "10:51:28 AM", "10:51:29 AM", 
"10:51:30 AM", "10:51:31 AM", "10:51:32 AM", "10:51:33 AM", "10:51:34 AM", 
"10:51:35 AM", "10:51:36 AM", "10:51:37 AM", "10:51:38 AM", "10:51:39 AM", 
"10:51:40 AM", "10:51:41 AM", "10:51:42 AM", "10:51:43 AM", "10:51:44 AM", 
"10:51:45 AM", "10:51:46 AM", "10:51:47 AM", "10:51:48 AM", "10:51:49 AM", 
"10:51:50 AM", "10:51:51 AM", "10:51:52 AM", "10:51:53 AM"), class = "factor"), 
    L = c(57.61, 57.16, 53.96, 57.3, 55.27, 57.9, 59.05, 55.13, 
    53.8, 57.59, 52.23, 57.93, 58.59, 56.27, 58.62, 61.25, 56.76, 
    56.64, 58.49, 53.99, 53.17, 56.77, 57.35, 53.43, 55.19, 54.5, 
    53.17, 53.88, 55.15, 61.81, 57.03, 55.97, 54.83, 59.53, 54.29, 
    56.84, 53.53, 55.38, 57.84, 58.32, 54.67, 52.72, 53.94, 55.17, 
    58.15, 53.55, 58.75, 56.07, 58.46, 60.33), C = c(4.56, 4.17, 
    5.14, 3.9, 3.63, 3.47, 4.3, 4.95, 5.76, 3.49, 4.7, 4.64, 
    5.64, 3.76, 2.25, 4.66, 5.96, 4.13, 5.32, 4.45, 4.11, 3.88, 
    5.47, 4.17, 5.92, 2.71, 5.2, 4.24, 5.78, 5.37, 4.71, 4.39, 
    3.83, 5.01, 4.62, 5.08, 4.74, 3.62, 3.59, 4.09, 3.32, 4.06, 
    4.09, 5.16, 3.1, 5.59, 3.06, 3.67, 4.56, 6.75), h = c(219.98, 
    226.13, 233.39, 221.78, 213.56, 214.16, 230.93, 229.57, 236.17, 
    230.59, 235.2, 237.58, 240.43, 228.53, 206.55, 234.13, 241.12, 
    231.82, 227.03, 231.32, 218.68, 230.31, 228.59, 229.36, 235.56, 
    197.32, 232.49, 228.39, 244.63, 235.78, 231.22, 228.92, 231.17, 
    244.2, 228.49, 234.01, 227.85, 226.29, 210.04, 232.38, 222.71, 
    220.69, 226.08, 233.15, 215.76, 236.26, 206.3, 219.79, 232.37, 
    246.63), L1 = c(57.61, 57.16, 53.96, 57.3, 55.27, 57.9, 59.05, 
    55.13, 53.8, 57.59, 52.23, 57.93, 58.59, 56.27, 58.62, 61.25, 
    56.76, 56.64, 58.49, 53.99, 53.17, 56.77, 57.35, 53.43, 55.19, 
    54.5, 53.17, 53.88, 55.15, 61.81, 57.03, 55.97, 54.83, 59.53, 
    54.29, 56.84, 53.53, 55.38, 57.84, 58.32, 54.67, 52.72, 53.94, 
    55.17, 58.15, 53.55, 58.75, 56.07, 58.46, 60.33), a = c(-3.49, 
    -2.89, -3.06, -2.91, -3.03, -2.87, -2.71, -3.21, -3.21, -2.22, 
    -2.68, -2.49, -2.79, -2.49, -2.01, -2.73, -2.88, -2.55, -3.63, 
    -2.78, -3.21, -2.48, -3.62, -2.72, -3.35, -2.58, -3.16, -2.81, 
    -2.48, -3.02, -2.95, -2.88, -2.4, -2.18, -3.06, -2.99, -3.18, 
    -2.5, -3.11, -2.5, -2.44, -3.08, -2.84, -3.1, -2.51, -3.1, 
    -2.74, -2.82, -2.79, -2.68), b = c(-2.93, -3.01, -4.13, -2.6, 
    -2.01, -1.95, -3.34, -3.77, -4.79, -2.7, -3.86, -3.92, -4.91, 
    -2.82, -1, -3.78, -5.22, -3.24, -3.89, -3.47, -2.57, -2.99, 
    -4.11, -3.17, -4.88, -0.81, -4.12, -3.17, -5.22, -4.44, -3.67, 
    -3.31, -2.99, -4.51, -3.46, -4.11, -3.52, -2.61, -1.8, -3.24, 
    -2.25, -2.64, -2.94, -4.13, -1.81, -4.65, -1.35, -2.35, -3.61, 
    -6.2), DE = c(36.52, 36.95, 40.24, 36.78, 38.77, 36.13, 35.08, 
    39.04, 40.47, 36.47, 41.92, 36.24, 35.72, 37.8, 35.35, 32.94, 
    37.57, 37.46, 35.74, 40.14, 40.9, 37.31, 36.9, 40.67, 39.11, 
    39.48, 41.02, 40.22, 39.15, 32.48, 37.13, 38.15, 39.24, 34.72, 
    39.84, 37.37, 40.61, 38.67, 36.2, 35.79, 39.35, 41.35, 40.14, 
    39.03, 35.86, 40.7, 35.25, 37.98, 35.69, 34.2), heihgtmm = c(53.1, 
    67.01, 80.16, 85.3, 86.37, 92.36, 91.12, 90.56, 91.02, 94.25, 
    96.79, 94.36, 96.26, 95.4, 93, 91.58, 91.92, 89, 81.52, 68.57, 
    53.54, 49.43, 54.31, 72.51, 81.95, 82.85, 86.77, 85.47, 90.1, 
    87.95, 90.1, 86.97, 89.42, 89.65, 87.56, 83.48, 76.43, 63.15, 
    54.92, 64.79, 67.47, 64.77, 61.6, 63.58, 69.27, 79.75, 83.41, 
    85.56, 88.47, 90.57), hex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("", "#507085", "#8A8F8C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", 
"Sample", "Time", "L", "C", "h", "L1", "a", "b", "DE", "heihgtmm", 
"hex"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

Comment: You need to tell ggplot to map to the hex colors. Does `+ scale_colour_identity()` fix your issue? If not, please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: It didn't work, I have posted the dataframe as output of the dput function
If right you should be able to see what I mean if you use my ggplot code

Comment: Ah. Several things going on: you have missing values in hex (as `""` is as far as I know not a hex color) and it's a factor. Do you want the hex names in the legend? Or do you just want the specified colours used in your plot?

Comment: No I only need to have colour to the datapoints. (are you saying color doesn't take the hex column because of the "" ?) I also tried to convert the factor variable to character... same thing.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying something like that. You cannot stipulate that points should have a certain colour, and then not provide a colour for some of the points. I'm working on an answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a new variable containing hex-values as character and added that variable into the aes.

```
#create a new variable, substituting red for missings and turning factor into string (you can add your own colour)
Trun$hex2 <- ifelse(Trun$hex=="","#CC0000",as.character(Trun$hex))

#plot    
ggplot(data=Trun, aes(x=X, y=DE, colour=hex2)) + geom_point(size=3) +  #larger vor visibility
  ggtitle("DE with 35* sd values") +
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I didn't know that such a call on colors needed to be complete. Gain exp by learning I quess.

Comment: You're welcome. Everybody has started at the beginning.